# How to configure WSO2 DAS server to get realtime stats from WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have configured WSO2 DAS server to receive statistics from WSO2 API manager. I want see realtime statistics. Is there any way to configure it, So that I will get realtime stats & test?

Comment: How do you publish data into DAS?

Comment: check this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

Comment: I have configured & using it by rest client. (With API Manager). But its not real time. Its take time to reflect in report/dashboard. I want it realtime.

Answer (score 0):

In [1] you can find an example CAR file that has a usecase of showing an alert in the DAS backend console which has used with CEP realtime execution engine. You may refer it and modify it for your requirements with APIM stats visualization.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Analyzing+Realtime+Service+Statistics